# Using CakeEmail with ajax method

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to send a simple email with CakeEmail on an ajax method. I assume the ajax call is the problem, which is returning a 400 bad request if I have the email function within it. Otherwise it works fine. Is there some special configuration I need to do to use CakeEmail within an ajax controller method? Or is this just not possible?

Just trying to run a standard CakeEmail, nothing out of the ordinary:

```
$email = new CakeEmail();
        $email->config = $this->ses;
        $email->from('contact@mydomain.com',Configure::read('Site.title'))
            ->to($user['User']['email'])
            ->subject(__d('croogo', '[%s] Discount Approved', Configure::read('Site.title')))
            ->template('Users.apply_approve')
            ->theme($this->theme)
            ->viewVars(array('user' => $user))
            ->send();
```

ses is a configuration in AppController:

```
    public $ses = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    'port' => 25,
    'username' => '****',
    'password' => '****',
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'tls' => true
);
```

I am using this in other areas (outside the ajax request) in regular form posts and it is working fine.

**UPDATE**
Checked the Apache logs (thanks Borislav), and it says:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function viewVars() on a non-object in...
```

So seems like with the Ajax request there are no viewVars which the CakeEmail is using:

```
->viewVars(array('user' => $user))
```

Comment: Please show some code! Without code, we will only be guessing on what you're trying to do. Read the [faq]. *note* you can edit your question and add the code via the [edit] link

Comment: @Michael it should not be the CakeEmail initialization but if could be that the email class cannot connect to it's "medium". What configuration are you using. Give us more information - how are you doing the AJAX request, what email configuration are you using, also check the web server logs to see what does the `400 Bad Request` relate to.

Comment: @Michael, try to get the email working with just a normal request first, then switch to AJAX. It will make debugging a little easier for you!

Comment: Thanks @Sam, Yes I did that and it works fine. The configuration is a simple SMTP configuration but I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

Removing

```
->theme($this->theme)
```

fixed it. The theme variable is not available in an ajax layout.